# asp.net mvc jquery model saving

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a form that is bound to a model. When the user clicks a link to leave that page, I would like to save the entire model to a database. I am wondering how I would go about calling a jquery event on a link click that would send the entire model to a controller function. Thank you!

Comment: Have you attempted anything at all, this is extremely common.

Comment: This is something a tutorial should be able to assist you with. This question is too vague to answer in general.  Try this example:  http://www.akhildeshpande.com/2011/08/simple-jquery-post-example-with-aspnet.html

Comment: Sorry for being too vague. If a user fills out a form, and then clicks a link to a different part of a site, I want to save all of the data that they have entered to the database before they leave the page. Since I am using model binding, I assumed that I would have to have a JQuery event that would serialize my model and send it to some controller on the server in order to save it in the controller action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax:

```
var form = $('form#formId'); 
$.ajax({
    url: ".../ControllerName/ActionName",
    type: 'POST',
    data: form.serialize(),        
    success: function (response) { 
        if (!response.ErrorMessage) {
            alert(response.ErrorMessage);
            return;
        } else {
            alert("Succesful.");
        }
    },
    error: function (error, textstatus) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(error));            
    }
});
```

For Action:

```
public JsonResult ActionName(ModelClassName object)
{
   try{
      ....
   } 
   catch(Exception e)
   {
       return Json(new { ErrorMessage = e.Message});
   }

   return Json(new { Success = true });
}
```